# splice array by value in Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of objects in my component and want to add functionality that when toggled, either get their `title` prop pushed onto an array or removed. The push part i implemented rather easily, however removing the value is pretty difficult since splicing by index doesn't help in this situation being that the items can be selected and pushed onto the array in any order:

**data**

```
data () {
    return {
        options = [
            {
                title: "pie",
                isSelected: false
            },
            {
                title: "cupcakes",
                isSelected: false
            },
            {
                title: "muffins",
                isSelected: false
            }
        ],
        selected : []
    }
},
```

**template**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
            v-for="(item, index) in options"
            :key="index"
            v-on:click="toggleSelected(index, item)">
            {{ item.title }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**script**

```
toggleSelected: function (index, item) {
    item.isSelected = !item.isSelected

    if (this.selected.includes(item.title)) {
        return this.selected.splice(item.title) // does not work as expected
    }
    return this.selected.push(item.title)
}
```

I know i am syntactically using `splice` incorrectly, so how do i achieve what i am looking to do? with or without `splice`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply filter it out?

```
return this.selected = this.selected.filter(title => title !== item.title);
```

Answer (score 2):

The expected parameters of the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function are the **start index** and the **delete count**

Which means that you'll have to do something like this:

```
this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(item.title), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[The correct form for splice is `(index, count, insert)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). The last parameter `insert` changes the behavior of the function to *add* to the array, as opposed to removing. To use splice here, you'll first have to get the index of the item, then specify that you want to remove one item by leaving the last parameter out.

```
const index = this.selected.indexOf(item.title)
if (index > -1) {
  this.selected.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Alternatively, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works as a simple alternative, and is the approach I'd go with here.

```
this.selected = this.selected.filter(title => title !== item.title)
```